# Add Items to late-bound SortedList in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sortedlist

I'm familiar with using Dictionaries in VBA, but I wanted to try out a SortedList. I read through the [msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) for it and thought it uses the same `.Add` structure as the Dictionary.

I've been struggling to actually populate the SortedList. I'm not sure how what I'm doing is any different from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42682697/1161309) from [How to make a list in VBA (not a dictionary)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681650/how-to-make-a-list-in-vba-not-a-dictionary). *I'd VTC my own question as Duplicate, but somehow it's not the same thing.*

I'm using a simple list:

[image]

And this is the Code -

```
Option Explicit

Sub testing()

    Dim sortList As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Set sortList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim i As Long
    Dim key As Variant
    Dim item As Variant

    For i = 1 To 7
        key = Sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
        item = Sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
        dict.Add key, item
        sortList.Add key, item
    Next

End Sub
```

I even went the extra step (just in case) and made everything `Variant` as I know the `SortedList` wants `Objects`.

I can't seem to retrieve anything from the SortList

What am I missing?

I'm trying to retrieve it the way I'd retrieve a dictionary

```
For Each key In sortList.keys
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = key
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 7) = sortList.item(key)
Next
```

Comment: Don't use the watch list to check the content - it doesn't show up there...

Comment: Fair enough, I did try printing it back out which is where it failed, essentially telling me there was no key. Maybe my print method is wrong, I'll post that.

Comment: http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Sortedlist_en.html

Comment: Thanks Tim, I feel ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the keys and items the wrong way out of the SortedList

```
For i = 0 To sortList.Count - 1
    key = sortList.getkey(i)
    item = sortList.item(key)
    Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 6) = key
    Sheet1.Cells(i + 1, 7) = item
Next
```

Different than in a Dictionary -

```
i = 1
For Each key In dict
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 6) = key
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 7) = dict(key)
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: `For i = 0 To sortList.Count - 1` would be more general usable.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I have always hated `For Each` loops with dictionaries.

Comment: @Raystafarian It is possible to loop through dictionary using index, though you must use early binding.

Comment: @AntiDrondert You can loop through a late bound dictionary using the Keys index.  The trick is to access the dictionary's Keys array.   `Key = dict.Keys()(i)`

Comment: @thomas news to me too!